# Change keyboard type depending on indexPath

Tags: image, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am making an app in which there is a custom UITableViewCell which has the criteria and then the user typed answer. I would like to change the keyboard type depending on which row is selected for user convenience.

eg. the "Cost" row would have to reveal a number pad keyboard for the user to type in and the "Suburb" row would have to reveal the standard keyboard for the user to type in.

Here's an image to help you guys. This cell would require the standard Keyboard.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGFhC.png

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. You can modify your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like this :

```
if (indexPath.row == 1)
{
     [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
}
else if ()
{
}..
```

Some Keyboard Types are :

```
UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing a textfield in the custom cell for entering the data, then

```
if (indexPath.row == 1)
{
     textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad; //(for number keypad)
}
```

There are different keyboard types.

For standard Keyboard use the enum `UIKeyboardTypeDefault`

In -cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellidentifier";

    CustomCell *tableCustomCell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (tableCustomCell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        tableCustomCell = self.customCell;
        self.customCell = nil;
    }
    //Here add the check for the textfields


    cell = tableCustomCell;
    return cell;

}
```

Hope this will help you.